# .NET Convert the contents of a DataTable to another DataTable with a different schema

Tags: sql, .net, linq, ado.net

I have a program where the user will have the option to map a variety of data source with an unpredictable column schema.  So they might have a SQL Server database with 10 fields or an excel file with 20 - the names can be anything and data types of the fields can be a mixture of text and numeric, dates, etc.

The user then has to provide a mapping of what each field means.  So column 4 is a "LocName", column 2 is a "LocX", column 1 is a "LocDate", etc.  The names and data types that the user is presented as options to map to is well defined by a DataSet DataTable (XSD xchema file).

For example, if the source contains data formatted like this:

```
User Column 1: "LocationDate" of type string
User Column 2: "XCoord" of type string
User Column 3: "YCoord" of type string
User Column 4: "LocationName" of type int
```

and the user provides a mapping that would require that translates to this for the **Application** required DataTable:

```
Application Column "LocName" of type string   = Column **4** of user table
Application Column "LocX" of type double      = Column **2** of user table
Application Column "LocY" of type double      = Column **3** of user table
Application Column "LocDate" of type datetime = Column **1** of user table
```

I have routines that connect to the source and pull out the data for a user query in "raw" format as a DataTable - so it takes the schema of the source.

My question is, what is the best way to then "transform" the data from the raw DataTable to the required application DataTable bearing in mine that this projection has to account for type conversions?

A foreach would obviously work but that seems like brute force since it will have to account for the data types with every loop on each row.  Is the a "slick" way to do it with LINQ or ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally do in select that "looks like" the destination table, but with data from the source table. You would apply the data conversions also as required.

```
Select
  Cast (LocationNameLocationName As varChar(...) As LocName
, LocX  As XCoord
, ...
From SourceTable
```

Hard to describe in a simple answer. what I've done in the past is issue an "empty" query like "Select * From sourcetable Where 1=0" which returns no rows but makes all the columns and their types available in the result set. You can cycle through the column ADO objects to get the type of each. You can then use that info to dynamically build a real SQL statement with the conversions.

You still have a lot of logic to decide the conversion, but they all happen as you're building the statement, not as the table is being read. You still have to say in code "if the source column is Integer and the destination column is character, then I want to generate into the select ', Cast ( as Varchar) '"

When you finish building the text of the select, you have a select you can run in ADO to get the rows and the actual move becomes as simple as read/write with the field coming in just as you want them. You can also use that select for an "Insert into  Select ...".

Hope this makes sense. The concept is easier to do than to describe.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  How would you deal with the fact that the DataType of the source can be anything at Runtime?

Comment: Thanks again.  Ok, thats kind of what I figured.  I was hoping for some kind of "magic" from LINQ or something else that I had not thought of but I suppose it was more wishful thinking - it cant do everyone for me I suppose. :)